# Get user mail based on username on profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I want to put contact form to user profile page via Contact Form 7 and [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) .Form on profile page will send messages directly to user on profile page. I need to put user email to  CF7 hidden field. This is only detail. Only code is important.I found a code but it's not working.

Profile Url  : domain.com/member/username

I need shortcode which get user email according to username on url.

```
 function func_print_user_email($user_email) {
        global $query_string;
        if($query_string != 'pagename=profile') {
            $patterns = '/(\w+)=(\w+)&(\w+)=/i';
            $username = preg_replace($patterns, '', $query_string);
        } else {
            global $current_user;
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $username = $current_user->user_login;
        }

        return trim($user_email);

        return "testshortcode= { trim$user_email[testshortcode] }";
    }
    add_shortcode('testshortcode', 'func_print_user_email');
```

THANKS FOR SUPPORT

Comment: what values does $query_string have?,what is the output of your shortcode?

Comment: Hi @madalin-ivascu,
For example;domain.com/profile/johndoe
.This is url where I put contact form for visitors can write directly to john doe.



[testshortcode] will get johndoe's email and message will be sent directly to johndoe.
Thanks for support.